# How to load a particular Layout in the xml file in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I don't know my question is correct or not. its only my thinking.if it is possible please give your comments..
My question is i have one xml file . it contain several layouts...

**is it possible to load only some layout part in the given xml file??**
my exact requirement is ,  see my xml code, it contains 3 types of layouts.
in the java part , when i click a button , then only some layout to be display and other are hidden , is this possible or not???

see my xml code

```
                 <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/background" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="122dp"
    android:layout_y="208dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="91dp"
    android:layout_y="90dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: No, your question is not clear. Please elaborate what is it that you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, my requirment is,when this xml file loaded , ineed to display only some layout in that xml..is it possible??

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Sanket answered your question. Now my question is: Why are you using an AbsoluteLayout? That doesn't look right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewFlipper for showing part of entire layout. ViewFlipper can have multiple child layouts to display at different situation like...

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First view is now displayed"></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second view is now displayed"></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Third view is now displayed"></TextView>
</ViewFlipper>
```

find flipper as..

```
ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
```

ViewFlipper shows one child(first one) at a time and other remains hidden. now to show other child you can write like...

```
flipper.setDisplayedChild(index);
```

Here index refers child number starting from 0, 1, 2,....

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Set visibility gone in xml code like this and check it

```
<android:visibility="gone"> to remove the layout
```

and set

```
 <android:visibility="invisible">   to make the layout invisible
```

Comment: Hi Sanket Pandya, thanx for your reply..your code is to change the visibility in the xml file..i have to done this in the java file

Comment: Use Layout.setvisiblity(View.GONE)

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.allocation); this is my xml file in the onCreate method. when i click some button action iin my activity class i need to load only some layout of the xml file...this is my requirment

Comment: LinearLayout YourLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

LoginLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Hi Sanket Pandya..exactly i want this...thanxxxxxxxxx very much